# C: Failed to compare character

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

I have C code as below. I have `abcd` as input, and my desired output is `aBcd`.

But at the line of `line1[i] == "b"`, I got the error saying that I am comparing pointer and integer... Why is "b" an integer?

I tried `"b" == line1[i]` instead but doesn't work. How can I got it fixed? Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

  char line1[10]="abcd";
  char line2[10];
    strcpy(line2, line1);

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    if(line1[i] == "b"){
      line2[i] = "B";
    }
  }

  printf("%s",line2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You *double-quote* strings, you *single-quote* characters....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
 if (line1[i] == "b")
```

You are comparing character, not string, so it should be:

```
if (line1[i] == 'b')
```

The error message you got:

> I got the error saying that I am comparing pointer and integer... Why
> is "b" an integer?

It actually means "b" is a pointer (it's char pointer), whereas your `line1[i]` is integer (which actually is a char).

You have the same problem with this:

```
line2[i] = "B";  //<-- should be 'B' instead
```